# How to disable CXF SOAP request validation?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, cxf

I'm using JAX-WS. Need to disable cxf usernameToken validation on client-side. Already tried:

```
((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put("schema-validation-enabled", "false");
```

but it didn't work. Still got exception caused by UsernameTokenInterceptor.

Comment: @petethepagan-gerbil org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: No username available

Comment: @petethepagan-gerbil any help?

Comment: Nope, just thought that information might help someone else.